# Selecting 2 Tables With Subquery

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

So I have 2 tables on my database. One table is an employee table and the other one is an employee performance table. In the performance table, I have a column called "ticket".

What I'm trying to do, is to select employees with the most tickets on the "Tech1" Departement

Here's the select that I got so far:

```
SELECT  e.Emp_name, p.Ticket
    FROM  employee e
    LEFT JOIN  performance p  ON e.id=p.id
    WHERE  p.Ticket = 
        ( SELECT  MAX(p.Ticket)
            FROM  tbl_ambilmk
            WHERE  p.departement="Tech1"
        )
```

However, the query doesn't work. It will show all employees and tickets from Tech1, not maxing them.

Comment: employees with the most tickets  - I don't get it surely only 1 employee can have the most (or possibly more than 1 in the case of draws) Please add sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  I hope that p.id i not an employee id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. But should be easier.

```
SELECT id,Emp_name FROM employee WHERE ID IN (
SELECT distinct ID FROM performance WHERE Ticket =(
SELECT MAX(Ticket) FROM performance WHERE departement='Tech1'))
```